# customize tabular

Tags: tables, rules

I want to customize my table using the `tabular` environments. So, I write :

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
 \hline
 colonne 1 & colonne 2 & colonne 3 \\
 \hline
 1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 \\
 \hline
 2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want to delete some line, something like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a combination of `\cline` and `\multicolumn` as demonstrated below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
 \cline{2-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{colonne 1} & colonne 2 & colonne 3 \\
 \hline
 1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 \\
 \hline
 2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

As a side note, have a look at the [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs) documentation for reasons not to use vertical rules in table.

Comment: +1 with the stress on the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package`